# In CSS, a way to say, if the TD element has IMG in it, then "text-align: center"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

The line

```
td img { text-align: center }
```

won't work.  It has to target the `td` instead: the `td` having an `img` element will have `text-align: center`.  Can it be done in CSS 2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use jQuery?  If you can then you can use a jquery selector to add a class to the td that will center it.

something like this untested code;

```
$('td img').parent().addclass('center');
```

Answer (score 1):

Cannot be done without the help of JS or...

Add a class to the td:

`<td class="img"><img .../></td>`